# Terminating thread which is blocking due to an I/O

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I created a thread that reads the serial port forever. It uses `readlines` to read the data in the serial port; if there are no data there, it blocks until data are received, once it has received data, it attempts to read again.

I can't terminate my program. If I call abort, the program doesn't close because, in one of the threads, `readlines` is blocking.  I can't terminate the thread either (for the same reason, I assume). How can I kill the thread despite `readlines` blocking?

Comment: Did my previous answer not help you (`read_nonblock`)? Do you still do blocking calls?

Comment: Yes it did -- thank you.  Problem is, I believe there is a bug in Ruby on Windows.  It throws a bad file descriptor error when I make a read_nonblock call and so it doesn't work...  So I need a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `interrupting` the thread and see if it helps.

Comment: but make sure to close any used resources such as sockets.